# How to disable tqdm's progressbar and keep only the text info in Pytorch Lightning (or in tqdm in general)

Tags: python, pytorch, progress-bar, tqdm, pytorch-lightning

I am working on Pytorchlightning and tqdm's progressbar is very buggy, it keep resizing back and forth from short to long, making reading the logging text so unpleasant, I realized that the progressbar is not really necessary and would like to keep only the info about the current epoch, current batch, accuracy, loss, etc.

From my searching it seems like you can disable whole tqdm display(progressbar and text), but how can I selectively disable only progressbar but not the text?

Comment: If you're on linux, I believe that tqdm pipes to stderr by default. So, you can pipe stderr to /dev/null by doing `python script.py --arg1 val1 2>/dev/null`. This should be done carefully as you won't see potential error messages when doing this either.

Answer (score 2):

The `tqdm` way to disable the "meter" (while retaining display of stats) is to set `ncols=0` and `dynamic_ncols=False` (see [tqdm documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#parameters)).

The way to customize the default progress bar behavior in `pytorch_lightning` is to pass a custom [`ProgressBar`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ProgressBar.html#progressbar) in as a callback when building the `Trainer`.

Putting the two together, if you wanted to modify the progress bar during training you could do something like the following:

```py
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ProgressBar


class MeterlessProgressBar(ProgressBar):

    def init_train_tqdm(self):
        bar = super().init_train_tqdm()
        bar.dynamic_ncols = False
        bar.ncols = 0
        return bar

bar = MeterlessProgressBar()
trainer = pl.Trainer(callbacks=[bar])
```

You can separately customize for the sanity check, prediction, validation, and test by overriding: `init_sanity_tqdm`, `init_predict_tqdm`, `init_validation_tqdm`, and `init_test_tqdm` respectively. (If you want a quick and dirty way to do something to all progress bars, you could consider overriding the [`_update_bar`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/progress.html#ProgressBar) method instead.)